# Pycharm exhibits same problem Ubuntu18, Mate18 and Mate20 -- packages cannot be installed

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package

Pycharm had been working well on Ubuntu18. Using Pycharm I had created several venvs and successfully installed packages in those different venvs. Today I created a new venv with Pycharm, tried to install a package and got this error message.

`Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/home/grass/PycharmProjects/astro/venv/bin/python'.`

Long story short, couldn't solve the problem. Reinstalled Pycharm, tried Mate18 with Pycharm instead with no success, and finally a pristine install of Mate20.

Python is what comes with Mate20; there are no upgrades. After I installed PyCharm I tried to install a package and the process failed again, with the above message, which is common to all my attempts on various machines.

From the terminal of the fresh install of Mate20 I get this

```
grass@m20:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
grass@m20:~$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
grass@m20:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
grass@m20:~$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

and from the PyCharm terminal I get this

```
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ which python
/home/grass/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ which python3
/home/grass/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python3
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ which pip
/home/grass/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/pip
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ which pip3
/home/grass/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/pip3
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ pip --version
pip 20.3 from /home/grass/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ pip3 --version
pip 20.3 from /home/grass/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$
```

Packages can be installed from the PyCharm terminal  eg

```
(venv) grass@m20:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ pip install astral
Collecting astral
  Downloading astral-2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2020.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 509 kB 2.5 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pytz, astral
Successfully installed astral-2.2 pytz-2020.4
```

What is going on with PyCharm? (or me!)
Thanks.

Comment: After good night's sleep I tried again with a fresh install of ubuntu18: Got the same problem.  Downgraded PyCharm to version pycharm-community-2019.3.5.tar.gz and I now have PyCharm which will install packages (again).

Comment: That was probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/65086897/2787185, updating to 2020.2.5 should resolve the problem as well.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I have noted that the upgrade is available. It's still a mystery, though, why my first installation worked OK for a few weeks before it became a problem.  Maybe I accidentally upgraded it while I was sober.