# Cann't install django with error 'Non-zero exit code (2)'

Tags: python, django

When i create new django project in pycharm i have error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlD3v.png)

Help me please

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details like error logs and add more details to your question.

Comment: I provide screenshot, where error. What details do you still need?

Comment: Try the proposed solution in that screenshot

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085956/pycharm-venv-failed-no-such-option-build-dir

Answer (score 1):

To not make project in the `venv/Scripts/` directory, add path while executing `django-admin startproject [project-name-that-you-want] [project-directory-path]` this command.
This will let you have your django project in the directory you want, so that your project directory looks like the ones that you can find in tutorial videos.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, PyCharm has given you a "proposed solution", so use that.

Basically, PyCharm is trying to add, or you have tried to add, a `--build-dir` argument to the pip command but pip doesn't know what `--build-dir` means.

Open your Terminal/Command Prompt, `cd` into your project directory and run `pip install django`.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Pycharm** settings and go to Interpreter settings `File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter` and `click` the `+` button on right side, then find `django` and
install it.