# How can I download SciPy on Python (PyCharm app)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, pycharm

I want to try to download SciPy, the library primarily used for machine learning.
I know that other people have asked this question but the solutions that worked for them didn't work for me, which is why I am asking it again.
I have tried downloading SciPy many times on PyCharm using terminal commands like "pip install SciPy"; "sudo pip install SciPy"; "pip install --upgrade SciPy"; "python3 -m install --upgrade pip"; among others, and I also went to the Python Packages section of PyCharm and tried downloading SciPy from there, with no success. I tried downloading NumPy using these methods and it worked, so the problem wasn't with the app. I am using Python 3.9.7, the pip version is 21.3.1, and PyCharm is on version 2021.2. This is what I get after every install attempt:
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/local/bin/python3.9'.
Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'dir:\projectPath\venv\Scripts\python.exe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538639/make-sure-that-you-use-the-correct-version-of-pip-installed-for-your-python-in)

Comment: Please refer,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58538639/14048816

Comment: I tried again after upgrading my pip to 21.3.1 (the latest available), and the download "worked" in the terminal and I tried using python on it. SciPy worked on the terminal in PyCharm, but when I went back to my code it shows that SciPy is still not installed.